Display a list as Modal
I want to display the list of cities of each state in a modal form when the user clicks on that state. Unfortunately, whatever I did, I could not solve this problem. I will show the ASP.NET Core code I wrote.
As you can see, in this query, we wrote two lines of code. In the first line, we applied a condition. When we apply the condition, nothing is displayed in the modal, but when we apply the second line, it means that we do not write the condition. Displays the database.
Query code:
public List<Parish> ShowParishByCity(int id)
{
    return _context.Parishes.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
}

Interface:
List<Parish> ShowParishByCity(int id);

Controller code:
public IActionResult ShowParish(int id)
{
    var pareshList = _iadvert.ShowParishByCity(id);

    var model = new ParieshViewModel
           {
             Parishes = pareshList,
            };

    return View(model);
}

View:
@model Paniaz.Core.ViewModels.ParieshViewModel 

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div style="height:1500px;width: 1238px;margin-right: -48px;">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Parishes)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
                <a asp-action="ShowAdverts" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="Id"
                   class="btn-city btn-block col-lg-2 text-center"
                   style="margin-right:20px;white-space:nowrap">
                    @item.Name
                </a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>


If the code with the where clause is not displaying anything, likely it's not finding any matches in the database. Most likely you are not mapping the id argument, and it simply ends up running the query with id=0. I would check and make sure your ShowParish action gets the correct input arguments.

Does parishList contain the data you expect when you drop a break point and inspect it?

I concur with @SzilardMuzsi 's comment that it's likely id does not contain the value you expect it to.  Have you verified the value of id in the ShowParishByCity method?  If it's not correct, backtrack to where you pass it from the View to the ShowParish method in the Controller.  My guess is that something is wrong with how you pass it from the View, but you haven't shown us that code.

It shows all results from database means the code correct. When passing null to modal it will report errors, which means your ShowParishByCity gets a 0 result instead of null.
In my test with random searching conditions when failing passing id to the interface, the id gets a default number 0 and returns a count 0 list.

So it is the issue that your id not passed correctly, considering that your other method lacked and no debug details.
